# Why do Java methods need return types

Tags: java, oop, methods, return-type

Apologies if this is quite a noobish question, but I've recently been trying to learn Java and find it difficult to accept the concept of return types -- I can't seem to find any justice to them.  There was however something on here of how they deviate from an original int return type thereby broadening what a method/function can return.  However, I still don't quite understand why: is there a functional reason for this? I.e. why can't the interpreter just simply return something if some line of code defines the returning of something.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 6):

I guess your implied question would be "why Java doesn't have type inference", since Java is obviously a statically-typed language, therefore the return type must be a definite known at compile time.

For the answer to that you could investigate Scala's type inference: it is really, really complex and messy, and the end result is still flaky. Java took the simple approach: **no type inference**. This is also in line with the stated design goal for Java to be a "blue collar language": explicit typing is more obvious and easier on low-skill developers.

For the record, I notice you mention the "Java interpreter", which would indicate that you mistake Java for a dynamic, interpreted language. Java is a compiled language.

Comment: Apologies for any incoherence or misunderstandings.  So ultimately, type inference is up to the programmer to implement? Anyway, I was essentially asking if this was an intentional reductionist approach of the language to provide more freedom with regards to programming, or if there were other genuine reasons/problems for why it's needed.  Nonetheless, I appreciate the responses sincerely.

Comment: No, a language either has or hasn't got type inference. There's nothing that you as a user of the language can do about it. You must provide the return type of each method. If you want dynamic typing, then you must use `Object` as the return type and determine the value types at runtime (this would not be type inference).

Answer (score 5):

For one, Java is statically typed, so without knowing return types, you couldn't assign the responses of functions to variables.

It also self documents the function to a degree.

For a lot of functions, `null` can also be returned.

Comment: +1 In the byte code, the return type is always required. In byte code, even constructors and static intializer blocks have a return type of `V` which is `void`

Answer (score 3):

Is is a design choice to catch some more errors on compile time as opposed to run time.

Answer (score 2):

Return types help enforce [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).